# Submit a form using href

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a form

```
<form method="post" id="ff">

<input type="name" id="aa" />

<input type="name" id="bb" />

<a href="http://www.example.php "> Submit </a>

</form>
```

Is it possible to post using the href ? I need to post the datas to href url.Is it possible?
Can someone help?

**I dont want to use the normal `action=`**

Comment: Why don't you want to use the action parameter?

Comment: Not wanting to use `action=` for this is like wanting to drive a car without turning on the engine.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I have a different application anyway.I know I can use action= but not for what im trying to do

Comment: @user3155047 Using the analogy above, instead of using the car's own engine you use another car to push it? Why? Do you want to be able to post the form to different targets using different buttons/links?

Comment: If you're going to break normal convention and ask for something that, on its face, is a terrible coding practice and shouldn't be done, at least give a really good use case in the question that explains why this monstrosity is really needed.

Answer (score 7):

You can try this

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.example.php" id="ff">
<input type="name" id="aa" />
<input type="name" id="bb" />
<a href="javascript: submitForm();"> Submit </a>

</form>
<script>
function submitForm(){
    $('#ff').submit();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use

```
<form method="post" id="ff" action="http://www.example.php">

...

</form>
```

Comment: KISS - this is the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this, but it will require JavaScript:

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('ff').submit();"> Submit </a>
```

You could also write more complex JavaScript functions and call that.

Comment: Please don't use the global arrays in `document`, very bad practice. Use specific IDs to retrieve a specific element.

Comment: Just because it might be bad practice for some people, it doesn't deserve a downvote IMHO.

Comment: Teaching people outdated coding styles which might break any day in current browsers most definitely deserves a downvote in my book, that's why the tooltip on the downvote button states *"This answer is not useful"*. It isn't.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes has a valid point; what i wrote was just a quick and dirty example.  Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the target URL as the `action` attribute of the `form`:

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.example.php">
```

Strictly speaking, what you ask is possible but not pretty:

```
<a href="http://www.example.php" 
   onclick="var e=document.getElementById('ff').action=this.href;e.submit();return false">Submit</a>
```

I'd go for the `action` instead...

Answer (score 0):

relace:

```
<a href="http://www.example.php "> Submit </a>
```

with:

```
<a href="http://www.example.php" onclick="frmsubmit(this);"> Submit </a>
<script type="text/javascript">
function frmsubmit(obj){
  var url = obj.href;
  document.getElementById('ff').action = url;
  document.getElementById('ff').submit();
}
</script>
```

if you have more than one  tag than use id and find it rather than by tag name

Comment: Why are you applying the `href` from the first anchor of the page?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes it was my mistake, thank you for letting me know. modified it now